# Is the behaviour of if(++i) ++i defined?

Tags: c

Suppose I have this code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = rand();
    if (++i) ++i;
    return i;
}
```

Is the behaviour defined here? I know that `i = ++i` is undefined and the second line in `main` contains a similar thing.  The `rand()` call is there to stop the compiler from optimising out what I think is the offending line.

Comment: there's a sequence point so I'd say yes

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Indeed I have.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: where is the sequence point? I hope you're correct. I'm in panic mode here: I have some code similar to this.

Comment: It's ugly code, but it looks like it should be defined.  I wouldn't recommend allowing anything that looks like that to ever make it into production code even if it is well defined.

Comment: Will your question fade away if you do something like `if (++i) { ++i; }` ? No? And if  `if (++i) { x=5; ++i; }` ?

Comment: I'm not a sequence point expert, but the execution has to test for condition first, then perform conditional code.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Yes that must separate out the execution of the program, but I don't know what formal mechanism does that.

Comment: Look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point *At the end of a full expression. This category includes expression statements (such as the assignment a=b;), return statements, **the controlling expressions of if**, switch, while, or do-while statements, and all three expressions in a for statement.*

Comment: Syntax has nothing to do with the behavior of the program, the fact that you can write a horrible `if (++i) ++i;` in a single line doesn't mean there is no sequence point between the two instances of `++i`. So it's just an ugly way to write something that in two lines is much less confusing. Note that if `i == -1` then `if (++i)` will not allow the next `++i` even to be executed.

Comment: @bolov C++17 doesn't apply to C

Comment: Java ended it way back in 1996 no?

Comment: Everybody is focusing on the sequencing issue, but do not forget that `++i` can overflow, so the behavior could be undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From C [**standard**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Cp1)

The following are the sequence points described in:-

> ....
>   Between the evaluation of a full expression and the next full expression to be evaluated. The following are full expressions: an initializer that is not part of a compound literal (6.7.9); the expression in an expression statement [**(6.8.3)**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.3); **the controlling expression of a selection statement (if or switch) [(6.8.4)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4);** the controlling expression of a while or do statement (6.8.5); each of the (optional) expressions of a for statement (6.8.5.3); the (optional) expression in a return statement.

So yes this is valid. I am just showing you the standard quote so that you feel satisfied that rule is stated somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is well-defined.

There's a sequence point after the evaluation of the expression `++i` in the `if` condition.

Comment: Phew. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 3):

This is well defined.

The condition of the `if` is first evaluated.  The side effect of incrementing `i` happens, then the incremented value of `i` is used as the controlling expression of the `if`.  In the event this evaluates to true, there is a sequence point before evaluating the statement in the body of the `if`, which is `++i`.